# Regex to match numbers, # @ % signs

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regex that matches all numbers (0-9) and # @ % signs.

I have tried **^[0-9#%@]$** , it doesn't work.

I want it to match, for example: 1234345, 2323, 1, 3@, %@, 9, 23743, @@@@@, or whatever...

There must be something missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost right... All you're missing is something to tell the regular expression there may be more than once of those characters like a `*` (0 or more) or a `+` (1 or more).

```
^[0-9#%@]+$
```

The `^` and `$` are used do indicate the start and end of a string, respectively. Make sure that you string only contains those characters otherwise, it won't work (e.g. "The number is 89#1" wouldn't work because the string begins with something other than 0-9, #, %, or @).

Comment: Good point, what should I add to the regex if I want it to match also when the string begins with something other than 0-9, #, %, or @?

Comment: @Matt - If you leave the `^` and `$` out, the regular expression will look for 0-9, #, %, or @ anywhere in the string.

Comment: @Matt - To extract the matches in a variable, you'll need to wrap the character class in parenthesis `()`. Here's a working example: [http://codepad.viper-7.com/0uDtEF](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0uDtEF).

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern `^[0-9#%@]$` only matches strings that are one character long. The [] construct matches a single character, and the ^ and $ anchors mean that nothing can come before or after the character matched by the [].

If you just want to know if the string has one of those characters in it, then `[0-9#%@]` will do that. If you want to match a string that must have at least one character in it, then use `^[0-9#%@]+$`. The "+" means to match one or more of the preceding item. If you also want to match empty strings, then use `[0-9#%@]*`. The "*" means to match zero or more of the preceding item.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `/^[0-9#%@]+$/`. The `+` is a qualifier that means "one or more of the preceding".

The problem with your current regex is that it will only match **one** character that could either be a number or `#`, `%`, or `@`. This is because the `^` and `$` characters match the beginning and the end of the line respectively. By adding the `+` qualifier, you are saying that you want to match one or more of the preceding character-class, and that the entire line consists of one or more of the characters in the specified character-class.

Comment: I think you my need to escape the '@' and '#' signs, so it would be `/^[\d\#%\@]+$/`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about PHP, but Perl requires them to be escape anyway.

Comment: That's not true either :). `perl -e 'print "true" if "123@##%" =~ /^[0-9#%@]+$/;'` prints `true`.

Answer (score 0):

remove the caret (^), it is used to match from the start of the string.

Comment: The caret is correct - he does want to match begin of the string

Answer (score 0):

You forgot "+"
^[0-9#%@]+$ must work